# My car starts fine but spits and sputters until I unplug my temperture sensor then runs without sputtering

Tags: electrical

I replaced the alternator and afterwords my car would start, but run like its missing. When I unplug my temp sensor it runs without the missing. Even when it's plugged up, you hit the gas and it wants to fall on its face.

Comment: its a 2001 Honda civic lx 1.7

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like what could happen if an EGR valve were opening when it shouldn't be - If your car even has an EGR. If it does, try unplugging it's vacuum hose (I'm pretty sure they still worked like that in 2001) and see if it gets better.

And does the temp sensor work correctly, if it's the same sensor that supplies the dash board temp gauge, does it indicate correctly? Not always cold or always hot?

It sounds like replacing the temp sensor might help.